# ¿Arreglo de objetos por parte de varias Clases?

Tags: java, array, herencia, objeto, clase-abstracta

Soy principiante en cuanto a POO, y ahora mismo estoy haciendo un código para una veterinaria donde debo realizar un arreglo de objetos y meter datos de animales.

Esta es la clase padre (La cual, como pueden ver es Abstracta)

`package veterinaria;`

`public abstract class Animal {`

```
private String nombre;
private int edad;
private int estatura;
private String sexo;

private String color;
private int peso;

Animal () {}
```

Y aparte hay 6 clases hija, Perro, Gato, Reptil, Roedor, Ave y Pez, todas estas con sus variables exclusivas y sus Getters y Setters.

`public class Perro extends Animal {`

`public Perro () {
     super();
    }`

```
protected byte numPatas;
protected String raza;
protected String vacunas;
protected String pedigree;
```

Mi duda en este caso es, si quiero meter diferentes datos de animales en un solo arreglo de objetos, ¿Qué podría hacer en este caso?

Desde antes le pido al usuario que ingrese qué animal deseará introducir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que estés bien.

Puedes crear una lista de objetos Animal, este es independiente de la clase hija a la que pertenece el objeto

```
public static ArrayList<Animal> animales = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Ahora, dentro de este listado de objetos, adicionarás algunos de los objetos de las clases hijas que quieras crear.

```
Perro kratos = new Perro(numPatas, raza, vacunas, pedigree);
Gato misifu = new Gato(numPatas, raza, vacunas, pedigree);
Reptil floyd = new Reptil(numPatas, raza, vacunas, pedigree);
```

Cabe recalcar, que las propiedades de cada animal anterior variará de acuerdo a las propiedades que tengas estipuladas en tus clases, no creo que un reptil tenga pedigre...

Luego, lo más importante es adicionar estos 3 objetos hijos a nuestro listado de Animales, para esto usaremos el método add

```
animales.add(kratos);
animales.add(misifu);
animales.add(floyd);
```

Espero te sirva mi ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Una consulta, intente agregar diferentes objetos de distintas clases hijas, pero tengo el problem de como acceder a propiedades especificas de un objeto de una clase hija, no me deja. como seria consultar por el metodo getter de kratos: animales.get(0).getTentaculos()